# Excel / Quickbooks data to c#

Tags: c#, excel, import, quickbooks

I know how to use the OleDbConnection class to open an excel file and select from it, but is there a simple method to read the data from an excel file that has been read into a Stream? And is there also a similar method for QuickBooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream? No, Excel files are a complicated mess.  Quickbooks, yeah.  I found this [ODBC driver](http://www.synergration.com/accessbooksrt/), it should support OdbcDataAdapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at various QuickBooks integration options, which allow you to communicate with QuickBooks via XML requests and responses. More details on the QuickBooks SDK here: 
http://developer.intuit.com/

Developer forums here: 
http://idnforums.intuit.com/categories.aspx?catid=56&entercat=y

VB .NET Framework here: 
http://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=56&threadid=11040&enterthread=y